# Не работает callback_data метод telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

не срабатывает callback метод от слова совсем что не так все перепробовал, менял func=lambda call: call.data == 'test' на func=lambda call: True' короче я хз [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1548324/234134