# Как сделать inline кнопку назад в telebot?

Tags: python, telebot, inline

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Заполнить анкету', url='https://gamergains.com')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Инфо', callback_data='Инфо')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Форум тема', callback_data='forum')
    markup.row(btn2,btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer (call):
    if call.data == "forum":
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('back', callback_data='back')
        markup1.row(btn4)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'https://google.com')
    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        main(message)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. необходимо использовать `InlineKeyboardMarkup()` для `markup1`
2. добавить `reply_markup` к `send_message` в блоке `if call.data == 'forum'`
3. вместо `elif message.text == 'Назад'` необходимо использовать `elif call.data == 'back'`
4. добавить изменение или отправку сообщения в блоке `elif call.data == 'back'` с указанием `reply_markup` со значением функции `main`

Итоговый код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Заполнить анкету', url='https://gamergains.com')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Инфо', callback_data='Инфо')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Форум тема', callback_data='forum')
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == "forum":
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('back', callback_data='back')
        markup1.row(btn4)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'https://google.com', reply_markup=markup1)

    elif call.data == 'back':
        bot.edit_message_text(call.message.text, call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=main(call.message))
```